# How do the pronouns work here?

Tags: pronouns

> È meglio che tu te ne vada.

I don't understand how the 'te' works here. I also don't understand why we need 'ne' if were just saying that its best if someone leaves. Could someone please explain why we need these pronouns here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Italian has so-called *verbi pronominali*, verbs that contain one or two pronouns as fixed parts. The verb here is not simply *andare*, but *andarsene*, and *se* changes to match the subject: *(io) me ne vado*, *(tu) te ne vai* and so on.